# PostgreSQL same date value for multiple rows when selecting date from one table

Tags: postgresql

```
select 34 as qwerty, date, bananas, cherry, apples, sum(carrots) as carrots, market='market'
from TABLE_NAME
where date between (now()::date - interval '30 days') and (now()::date)  
group by 2,3,4,5,7
```

I have this query but I do not know why I have this result which has same that for multiple row. Please tell me how to fix this and explain me what is wrong with this query because I can not find what is the problem.

```
34;"2017-08-09";282;1;0;245
34;"2017-08-16";0;0;0;1
34;"2017-07-24";3;0;0;3
34;"2017-08-09";7;0;0;7
34;"2017-08-02";221;16;0;283
34;"2017-07-17";3;0;0;3
34;"2017-07-17";252;3;1;263
34;"2017-07-30";2;0;0;2
34;"2017-08-06";7;0;0;7
34;"2017-08-10";249;3;0;271
34;"2017-07-21";9;0;0;9
34;"2017-08-05";1;0;0;1
34;"2017-08-07";264;0;1;280
34;"2017-08-08";231;2;0;249
34;"2017-07-31";286;2;0;222
34;"2017-08-06";208;4;0;234
34;"2017-07-28";308;3;0;268
34;"2017-07-18";313;3;0;263
34;"2017-07-27";289;2;0;289
34;"2017-07-29";230;4;1;272
34;"2017-08-03";285;5;0;290
34;"2017-07-20";2;0;0;2
34;"2017-08-08";8;0;0;8
34;"2017-08-01";4;0;0;4
34;"2017-08-14";4;0;0;4
34;"2017-08-13";4;0;0;4
34;"2017-08-11";272;2;0;269
34;"2017-08-14";289;2;0;271
34;"2017-08-03";7;0;0;7
34;"2017-08-04";6;0;0;6
34;"2017-07-24";169;3;1;271
34;"2017-07-28";5;0;0;5
34;"2017-07-23";5;0;0;5
34;"2017-07-22";201;3;0;291
34;"2017-08-12";2;0;0;2
34;"2017-07-22";2;0;0;2
34;"2017-07-21";357;3;0;322
34;"2017-08-05";262;5;1;251
34;"2017-07-20";301;5;0;307
34;"2017-07-29";5;0;0;5
34;"2017-07-18";4;0;0;4
34;"2017-07-25";337;4;0;260
34;"2017-07-31";6;0;0;5
34;"2017-08-15";5;0;0;5
34;"2017-07-27";8;0;0;8
34;"2017-08-04";293;4;0;273
34;"2017-07-26";420;2;0;299
34;"2017-07-19";2;0;0;2
```

Comment: `which has same that for multiple row` ... I don't see any duplicate rows at all.  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Why are you only summing carrots? It would seem to make more sense to sum bananas, cherries and apples as well, and then group by date?  You get multiple dates because there are more than one records with the other fields on the same date.